# Imperative vs Functional by example

Tags: scala, functional-programming, imperative-programming

I have a method implemented in imperative and functional (I did my best here) ways. The method iterates over ArrayBuffer[Creature], calculates distance to each creature and return the closest or None (if no creatures in the world except 'this').

Imperative:

```
private def closestEnemy: Option[Creature] = {
  var closest: Option[Creature] = None
  var distanceToClosest = Int.MaxValue

  for(creature <- game.creatures if creature != this) {
    val distance = distanceTo(creature)

    if(distance < distanceToClosest) {
      closest = Some(creature)
      distanceToClosest = distance
    }
  }

  closest
}
```

Functional:

```
private def closestEnemy: Option[Creature] =
  game.creatures filter { _ != this } map { creature => (creature, distanceTo(creature)) } match {
    case creaturesWithDistance if creaturesWithDistance.isEmpty => None
    case creaturesWithDistance => Some(creaturesWithDistance minBy { _._2 } _1)
  }
```

The functional code looks less obvious (probably it can be simplified but I don't see how) and I'm not sure if I am able to read it on fly in a month. My question is it a matter of habit or functional isn't good for this particular case? Did you have such doubts when started Scala? Did your functional skills greatly improved after some time and totaly beat the imperative approach? Please post your experience.

Thanks!

Comment: Try these: http://aperiodic.net/phil/scala/s-99/

Comment: It's sad that this question is not valid here (_or_ in programmers). I suggest you try some other place that is receptive of open-ended questions, such as [Quora](http://quora.com). Meanwhile, you could post the functional code to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) asking for feedback on it.

Comment: Other forums that are more appropriate for open-ended discussion questions such as this are [/r/scala](http://reddit.com/r/scala) and the #scala irc channel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your primary goal is readability, the following gives the same output as your code:

```
private def closestEnemy =
  game.creatures.filterNot(_ == this).sortBy(distanceTo).headOption
```

This seems extremely clear to me—there's very little syntactic noise, particularly compared to your imperative version.

Unfortunately `sortBy` is more expensive than `minBy`, and even more unfortunately there's no "safe" `minBy` in the Scala Collections API (where "safe" means that it returns an `Option` that's empty when called on an empty list). The following isn't too terrible, though:

```
private def closestEnemy = game.creatures.filterNot(_ == this) match {
  case creatures if creatures.nonEmpty => Some(creatures.minBy(distanceTo))
  case _ => None
}
```

So in this case you've run into a legitimate shortcoming of the Collections API (no `safeMinBy`), but I'd still personally much prefer to maintain this code than your imperative version.

---

As a footnote: it's worth noting that you can use the [pimp-my-library pattern](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=179766) to "fix" the Collections API. Just put the following in scope somewhere:

```
implicit def makeSeqSafer[A](xs: Seq[A]) = new {
  def safeMinBy[B: Ordering](f: A => B) =
    if (xs.isEmpty) None else Some(xs.minBy(f))
}
```

Now you've got a safe, efficient `minBy`:

```
scala> List(1, 2, 3).safeMinBy(_ * 2)
res0: Option[Int] = Some(1)

scala> List.empty[Int].safeMinBy(_ * 2)
res1: Option[Int] = None
```

And in your case:

```
private def closestEnemy =
  game.creatures.filterNot(_ == this).safeMinBy(distanceTo)
```

Comment: My primary goal is easy code supporting. I'd like to be able to change the code easily if needed and don't spend few minutes trying to understand what it does. So do you think that support functional code isn't more difficult than imperative? That's what I'm mostly awared of now :)

Comment: It's ultimately a matter of taste to a large degree, but in my experience maintaining functional code can be easier. It's certainly possible to go too far in the direction of concision and cleverness—I wrote some extremely impenetrable Haskell when I was first learning to think functionally—but it's also possible to balance concision and maintainability.

Answer (score 7):

You can do this simpler by using collect:

```
game.creatures collect { case creature if creature != this => (creature, distanceTo(creature)) }
```

`collect` takes a `PartialFunction` and will only return values at which this function is defined, so `creature == this` will not be returned.

And also you can replace

```
case creaturesWithDistance if creaturesWithDistance.isEmpty => None
```

with

```
case Seq() => None
```